# FAC woocom plugin - transaction declined but not logs found at FAC

Tags: omnipay

First Atlantic Commerce woocom plugin - transaction declined but not logs found at First Atlantic Commerce backend portal.

Can you please advise on this?

Tried First Atlantic Commerce woo commerce plugin and it is not working as expected.